# how to iterate a nested loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, range

```
i=5
while(i>=1):
    for j in range (6,i):
        j-=1
        print(j,end='\n')

    print(i,end='\n')
    i-=1
```

I should get this required
output

```
5
4 4
3 3 3
2 2 2 2 
1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: If you're iterating down, you need `range(6, i, -1)`

Answer (score 2):

You could try making the code shorter:

```
i=5
while(i>=1):
    for j in range (6 - i):
        print(i, end=' ')
    print()
    i-=1
```

Output:

```
5 
4 4 
3 3 3 
2 2 2 2 
1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
n=5
List=[]

for i,j in zip(range(1,n+1),range(n,0,-1)):
    List.append(f"{i} "*j)
    
List.reverse()

for i in List:
    print(i)
```